# batch file to share folders in windows 7

Tags: powershell

What would be the easiest way to run a batch / script file in Windows 7 to share 30 folders, each to a different user? They must write their backups over the network to this one PC standing separately with a huge HDD on which there is 30 folders.

Each person has his/her own folder to which he/she must get full access, but nobody else. Apologies but I'm new to Win7 and scripting.

Powershell? It must e.g. create the share John$, on the folder C:\John, with permissions = person John only, who has userid XYZ12345 on our network. And then for the other 29 people too, each with their own folder name and user id.

Trust me, I really did try to browse around but I'm getting more and more confused.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`net share <share name>=<drive>:<dir> /grant:<user>,FULL /remark="description"`

Will create the share with full permissions for  - for more detailed permissions you might have to use setacl.exe

Answer (score 1):

So the individual pieces you need from the command line are:

1. A way to iterate through users' names
2. A way to create a directory
3. A command to share a folder with a particular permission set

You should be able to do that with a plain old batch script.  Looping through a list of names is easy, depending on how you want to specify the names.  You could do something like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ("John Mary Matt Greg") DO ...
```

Where "..." is a subroutine to create the folder and share.  That's where [`net share`](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_NET_SHARE_to_Configure_Windows_Server_2008_File_Sharing#Net_Share_Command-line_Syntax) comes in.  For each user you can do something like:

```
MKDIR %1
NET SHARE %1=%1 /GRANT:%1
```